# Can projective measurements of a qubit be written as conditional probabilities of a distribution on the sphere?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, mathematical-physics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

Let $\Psi :=p_1|\psi_1 \rangle \langle \psi_1 | + p_2|\psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_2|$ be a density matrix/operator representing a (possibly mixed) qubit state. A projective measurement corresponds to a pair of (equivalence classes of) orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{CP}^1$, and choosing arbitrary representatives $\langle \phi_1|$, $\langle \phi_2|$ from such an equivalence class, for a fixed $\Psi$ the projective measurement corresponds to the Bernoulli distribution $\mathbb{P}(X=1) = p_1 |\langle \phi_1 | \psi_1 \rangle |^2 + p_2|\langle \phi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle |^2$, $\mathbb{P}(X=2) = p_1 |\langle \phi_2 | \psi_1 \rangle |^2 + p_2|\langle \phi_2 | \psi_2 \rangle |^2$. The projective measurement also corresponds to a pair of antipodal points on the sphere (using the Bloch sphere parameterization).

> **Question:** For a given qubit state $\Psi$, can all of these Bernoulli distributions corresponding to projective measurements be written as a conditional disintegration of a distribution on the sphere?

This appears to be possible in at least one case, namely if $\Psi$ is the perfectly mixed state $\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then all of the Bernoulli distributions corresponding to projective measurements are "fair coins", i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X=1) = \frac{1}{2} = \mathbb{P}(X=2)$. Hence these distributions should form a conditional disintegration of the uniform distribution on the sphere.

**Note 1:** Even if such a construction works for qubits, I doubt it has any real-world relevance / "physical explainability", because it would not seem to be applicable to e.g. qutrits or other quantum systems with more than two states. Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4696783/can-a-qutrit-mathbbcp2-be-simulated-by-two-qubits-two-copies-of-mat).

**Note 2:** For more on conditional disintegration, cf. e.g. the references [1] [2] below, or these other questions [[a]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/conditional-probability-and-the-disintegration-theorem) [[b]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834037/from-disintegration-to-conditioning) on math stackexchange.

**Note 3:** I am familiar with contextuality, counterfactual indefiniteness, and Bell-type inequalities for stochastic hidden variables. However all of these only seem to be obstacles for writing the Bernoulli distributions corresponding to projective measurements of a qubit as *marginal* distributions of a common joint distribution.

As far as I understand, they don't seem to say anything that prohibits writing those distributions as *conditional* distributions of a common "mixture distribution". Marginalization and conditioning in general can behave very differently.

**Note 4:** Because the family of [von-Mises Fisher distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution) (restricted to $0 \le \kappa \le 1$, $p=3$) has a parameterization very similar to that of the Bloch sphere, and because ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution#Definition)) it has been used to model the interaction of electric dipoles in an electric field, it is *very* tempting to imagine that a conditional disintegration of these distributions could correspond to projective measurements of a qubit. That was the motivation for a [question I asked previously on the stats stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/615784/is-there-an-antipodal-conditional-disintegration-of-the-von-mises-fisher-distr). However, even if the vMF distributions are unrelated, that doesn't by itself prohibit the possibility of writing the projective measurements of a qubit as a conditional disintegration of some other distribution on the sphere.

**References:**
[1] [*Conditioning as disintegration*](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Ejtc5/papers/ConditioningAsDisintegration.pdf), J. T. Chang and D. Pollard, Statistica Neerlandica (1997) Vol. 51, nr. 3, pp. 287±317

[2] sections 2.2. and 2.3 of [*Exact Bayesian Inference by Symbolic Disintegration*](https://homes.luddy.indiana.edu/ccshan/rational/disintegrator.pdf), Chung-chieh Shan and Norman Ramsey, POPL’17, January 15–21, 2017, Paris, France
ACM. 978-1-4503-4660-3/17/01. http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/3009837.3009852